# altering text returned from source

Tags: php, xml

This code pulls the name of a shipping option from Canada Post's server.  I need to somehow specify that if it comes back as "Expedited" it should say "Canada Post" instead.  Is that possible?

```
$name = substr(
   $resultXML,
   strpos($resultXML, "<name>") + strlen("<name>"),
   strpos($resultXML, "</name>") - strlen("<name>") - strpos($resultXML, "<name>")
);
```

Comment: You can split up a statement over multiple lines. Might make it easier to digest

Comment: *" Is that possible?"* -- Yes, sure! That **is** indeed possible. [More help is available at your fingertips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement:

```
if ($name === 'Expedited') {
    $name = 'Canada Post';
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: Don't forget to [accept answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simple xml parser which is built into php

```
// make it more error friendly
$saved = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

//load the xml as object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($inputString);
if ($xml === false) { 
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo $error->message, "\n";
    }
    libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);
    return;
}

libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);

echo $xml->asXML(); //you can see the XML here
```

get the name as per object position like `$xml->obj1->name` etc